# Which distribution would be the most appropriate?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

What standard distribution would be suitable for the random phenomenon at hand, and what are the knowns and unknowns?

e) The size of an automobile insurance claim

I'm thinking that the distribution has to be continuous and whose density is non-negative on the entire interval $[0 , ∞)$. Would the gamma distribution be appropriate here?

Comment: How about Poisson? Assuming independence.

Comment: a density is non-negative everywhere. maybe you mean the density is 0 outside that interval.

Comment: Once you have decided to go for a continuous distribution with support only on positive values, anything further can only really be judged empirically. [This paper](http://www.actuaries.org/EVENTS/Congresses/Cape_Town/Papers/Non-Life%20Insurance%20(ASTIN)/22_final%20paper_Oyugi.pdf) considers the log-normal, exponential, gamma and Weibull distributions potentially plausible and then finds that the log-normal appears to fit particular data more closely than the others.